# Error connecting to localhost on port 4445. with Nightwatch and Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, port, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run my script using Nightwatch(Javascript), but I'm getting this error :

```
      \ Connecting to localhost on port 4445...

     ‼ Error connecting to localhost on port 4445.
      × failed
        Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "session not created: This 
        version 
       of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90"   

      × failed
      Error: Nightwatch client is not ready.
                Looks like function "createSession" did not succeed or was not called yet.
      at Object.globals [as get] (C:\automation-Nightwatcg-12-27\QA Automation 
     \node_modules\nightwatch-api\lib\proxy.js:21:17)
      at World.<anonymous> (C:\automation-Nightwatcg-12-27\QA 
      Automation\/cucumber.conf.js:72:17)
```

From nightwatch.js.conf

```
    webdriver: {
    start_process: !Boolean(process.env.NIGHTWATCH_SELENIUM_GRID),
    port: process.env.NIGHTWATCH_SELENIUM_PORT || 4445,
   
    },
```

I tried to run ChromeDriver

```
  Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch- 
  heads/4664@{#947}) on port 9515
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
  keeping ChromeDriver safe.
  ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

So when running ChromeDriver, I can see it is running on port 9515 .
I tried to edit the file nightwatch.js.conf  with the port 9515 , but it didn't work.

I also did those steps, but they didn't help
Delete your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Then do npm cache clean
1-npm cache clean --force
2-npm install

It seems I have a port conflict
Does anyone has an idea to to proceed with this issue ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90

This straight away looks to me like a compatibility issue between the chrome version you have on your machine and the chrome driver version you are using. maybe you need to update both of them to be compatible.

Comment: Thank you Raju , you are right , I was inserting the updated vision of chrome.exe under the wrong file under Lib instead of bin .